# Magento URL Management not working with same path ID

Tags: magento

I am having on issue in magento URL Management. While doing custom URL for SEO some of the target path already exist in magento so it will give me error regarding "**ID Path**" or "**Request Path for Specified Store already exist**" error but i want to use that ID Path even though it's already exist.If any one having idea about how to do this.

[image]

Comment: *"i want to use that ID Path even though it's already exist"* - why?

Comment: Multiple identical keys... probably not a good idea. People are always wondering where those integrity check errors come from.

Comment: actually my client's site before i launch the new one is in osCommerce so google clone that urls so i want to redirects those url in my client's new mangento site but magento by default do some Redirect mgmt and i have much more urls which redirect to same page or same products so i want to know weather it's possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

you would have to change the item that currenlty has the path you want first before you can create your URL with the already used path